# Ford Fiesta 2005 1.2 Petrol Clutch Replacement

Tags: oil, clutch

I'm going to be replacing the clutch on my Ford Fiesta 2005 1.2 Petrol soon. I've seen some videos online, in which they drain and top up two different types of oil.

I was wondering if anyone could let me know what oils I need to top up and how much I will need?

This is the [best video I've found](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xx8ilz5fI2g), even though it's for a 1.4 but I don't think there is much difference.

- Draining @ 1:36
- Draining @ 8:53
- Topup @ 27:09
- Topup @ 38:50

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first drain (1:36/38:50) is transmission fluid. Ford recommends you use [WSD-M2C200-C Transmission Oil](https://garage.wiki/ford/fiesta-hatchback/fifth-generation-mk5/2005/manual-transmission-oil-capacity.html)

The second (8:53/27:09) is brake fluid associated with the hydraulic clutch master/slave system. The brake master cylinder reservoir feeds this. It should be DOT3 or 4, however, to keep you covered, DOT4 will work just fine. It mixes just fine with DOT3 if that's what the system uses. If it's DOT4 which is needed, you're covered. You cannot put DOT3 into DOT4 and expect the proper performance. The other way around works just fine though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond! Do you know roughly how much of each I'll need? I know this is a top up so 1ltr of both should be plenty.

Comment: It depends on how much is needed. I'd bet the tranny could need up to 2ltr ... the brake fluid a very small amount, probably less then 1/2 ltr.